# What event IDs correspond to changes in Windows Add or Remove Programs dialog?

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, eventviewer

What event does Windows log when a component is registered with Windows "Add or Remove Programs" or more recently "App & features" dialog?

While events with ID 11707 represent many of the applications in that dialog, they don't include all of them (they don't seem to include Google Chrome which is present in the dialog).

Answer (score 0):

The backend of that GUi is the MsiInstaller service

And MsiInstaller has a lot of events
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/event-logging